# VBA Macro to Autofill a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to find a simple autofill solution to copy the formula in cell C3 into C2 after a new line has been inserted. Here is what I have that I thought would work:

```
Sub AutoFill()
    Set SourceRange = Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("C3")
    Set fillRange = Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("C2")
    SourceRange.AutoFill Destination:=fillRange
End Sub
```

Basically, in C3 (and every cell in column C after row 3) has a average function that takes the previous 20 days and creates an average. I am trying to get the macro to input that formula everytime a new row gets put in (I have the code to input the new row it just won't apply the function after the new row comes in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The cells to be filled. The destination must include the source range.

As quoted from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195345(v=office.15).aspx).

So try:

```
Set SourceRange = Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("C3")
Set fillRange = Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("C2")
SourceRange.AutoFill Destination:=Range(fillRange, SourceRange)
```

Another note is to use *Named ranges* if you are inserting rows in between.

Comment: This works perfect. Thank you for referencing MSDN as well.

Comment: Additionally, I got that code from MSDN originally excep it wasn't `(fillrange,SourceRange)` that seems to be what fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Other ways to get formulas with updated cell references

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub getFormula()
    With Sheet1
        .Range("C3").Copy
        .Range("C2").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas

        If .ListObjects.Count = 1 Then
            With .ListObjects(1)        'for tables
                .Cells(2, 3).Formula = .Cells(3, 3).Formula
            End With
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

.

Also, you should not use the name of VBA method as a sub name (AutoFill)

- A fast way to determine VBA keywords: click on the sub name and press F1

  If the help page shows **Keyword Not Found** your sub name should be Ok

Comment: It works to copy the formula into the cell, however, it uses the same cell references as the formula below instead of updating to a new range. I.e. The cell below has a formula that is `Average(C3:C22)` and the one above needed to change to the same formula excep be `Average(C2:21)`